# Why we can write $dx/dt$ instead of $x'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I want to solve an equation like $x' = -2t(x+1)$, I will write $$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = x'\;\;\implies\;\;\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -2t(x+1)$$ and then I can solve it for $x$.

But why is it possible to write $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ instead of $x'$?

Comment: Its a shorthand for $\frac{dx}{dt}$

Comment: Are you asking why [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) works or is this question (only) about the notation $\frac{dx}{dt}$ as the other comments suggest?

Comment: As Amr said, it is simply a shorthand for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ so they are synonyms.  It just saves some writing and vertical space when typesetting.

Comment: What happened to the convention that $y'$ means $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\dot{y}$ means $\frac{dy}{dt}$ ?  The question uses it the other way.  Is the convention only used in physics?

Comment: fixed tag: not (difference-equations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...why is it possible to write $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ instead of $x'$?

$$x' = -2t(x+1)\iff \frac{dx}{dt} = -2t(x+1)$$

I.e., $\;x'\;$ is "shorthand" for $\;\dfrac{dx}{dt}$.

What's nice about $\;\dfrac{dx}{dt}\;$ is that it specifies the derivative of $\;x\;$ with respect to $\;t$. 
But the same is taken as given when you see $\;x' = -2t(x+1),\;$ which is more brief than using $\;\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -2t(x+1)$.

If you also have $y' = at(y + b)$ where $a, b$ are given, you could write $\;\dfrac{dy}{dt} = at(y + b)$. If you know $\;\dfrac{dy}{dt}\;$ and $\;\dfrac{dx}{dt},\;$ you can solve for $dy/dx$:

$$
\begin{align*} \dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt} &= \dfrac{dy}{dt} \\ \\
\text{So}\;\;\;\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}\end{align*}$$